# Does jQuery support ftp request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a web project and I would like to add a functionality like Fire FTP plugin in Firefox. So I want to send FTP requests using jQuery to read the local drive of the computer. I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

UPDATE - I want to make a functionality like user enter drive name in one window then second window display that drive directory and file. I want to open directory/file from local drive not from server. so my question is it is possible using java-script or not?

Comment: Nope, not possible without a custom browser plug-in... the usual workaround is to upload to a web form on server side, which then can make a FTP operation if necessary

Comment: jQuery is javascript, and javascript has a same origin policy and does not support connecting to cross domain url's at all.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is: would you want any website built with Javascipt/jQuery to have access to personal files on your computer? Probably not - and that's the reason why it's not possible. You can still build a web-based, FTP-style client, but you allow the user to select files themselves using `input="file"` and post them to the server with AJAX. You could then FTP out from the server page.

Answer (score 4):

JQuery is JavaScript, and Javascript only says to browser what to do. Javascript doesn't make HTTP requests, browser does.

FTP = File Transfer Protocol, so it's certainly for transferring files. Javascript has not been created for modifying files, so it's a bit impossible.

You can redirect user to URI `ftp:...`, but only if browser supports FTP, or use server-side scripts

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it in jQuery only. jQuery is a Javascript client language and you don't have the ability to manage (or even explore) files and directories on your server with it. BUT you might consider using some plugins which require using server side code (PHP, ASP.net, Python etc). If you do need to manage files on your server, use one of those (googled them up, but never tried them):

http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/

http://www.gleamtech.com/products/filevista/web-file-manager

Good luck! I hope that helped.

Comment: hello sir, i want to open my local drive directory and file of specific drive. so it is possible using java script?

Comment: the only thing you can do, is to try to get that file and if it doesn't exit, you will get error, but you cant do edit/search/add/delete with files if you using ONLY JavaScript. you can do it with server side language like Python, PHP, ASP.net etc