# read file from ftp server

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, ftp

What is the best way to read the content of a FTP file from within a HTML5-App?

I have tried:

```
$.ajax
({
    async: false,
    url: 'ftp://ftp.XXX.de/Sonstiges/XXX.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout:30000
})
.done(function (data)
{
         //...
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus)
{
        //...
}
```

but I always get into fail, probably because of a cross-domain security error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... There is one thing you need to take into account: ajax request could only send HTTP request, please refer to [Does jQuery support ftp request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761373/does-jquery-support-ftp-request)

Comment: FTP is a different protocol from HTTP. Basically you are asking someone who only speaks Swedish to starts speaking Swahili.

Comment: @simpleBob, I don't think there is any way to read a FTP file from pure HTML5 app, you could try some client solution, such as activX, java applet if you want to download a FTP file from browser.