# Upload file via FTP using javascript (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ftp

I have a chrome extension, so it's pure javascript + chrome api. I want to upload via FTP protocol a file.

I have understood that vanilla javascript can't do FTP request. But is there any other way ? I'm in a Chrome extension but I haven't find any ftp purpoes in the online API

And I have to clarify, I have to upload a file via FTP on black box. I don't have any control on it. And this black box is not accessible via Internet, only via local network.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761373/does-jquery-support-ftp-request

Comment: JavaScript only understands HTTP and WebSockets, it does not have support for any other protocol. You need to be using a server-side language to achieve this, i.e PHP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: @JoshStevenson So why it get a response ? If it doesn't support ftp request it should alert KO or throw an exception, no ?

Comment: What response is it getting Emrys

Comment: Ok... The serveur serv an html page when trying to access it by port 80...

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you can use the [chrome-app-ftp](https://github.com/MikeCostello/chrome-app-ftp) library

```
var ftpClient = new FtpClient(host, port, user, password);

ftpClient.connect().then(function () {
   ftpClient.upload("test.txt", buffer)
});
```

But the socket api doesn't available in extensions.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13922297/1850255) is more information about it